# Magento unique TaxVat atrribute for every customer

Tags: magento, attributes, unique

.Hi,
I'm trying to make the attribute taxvat unique for every customer. (especially for users that i create from the backend). i.e no duplicates.
Just like the email attribute, if the email is already used, user gets notified to use another email.
I tried from the eav_attribute to change "is_unique" to "1" but nothing happened..
Can you please help me how to achieve this..?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found the solution..
Find file /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Form.php (Don't forget to override instead..)
in "public function validateData(array $data)"

add the code inside the 
foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $attribute)

```
foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
...
...
//## code to add
        if ($attribute->getIsUnique()) {
            $cid = $this->getEntity()->getData('entity_id'); //get current customer id
            $cli = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()]);
            //->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',   array('neq' => $cid)); //exclude current user from results  //###### not working......
            $flag=0;
            foreach ($cli as $customer) {
                 $dataid=$customer->getId();
                 if ($dataid != $cid) //if the value is from another customer_id
                    $flag |= 1;  //we found a dup value
            }

            if ($flag) {
                $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
                $errors = array_merge($errors, Mage::helper('customer')->__('"%s" already used!',$label));
            }
        }
//## End of code to add
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified what Karpa wrote to make it better

```
if ($attribute->getIsUnique()) {
            $cid = $this->getEntity()->getData('entity_id'); //get current customer id
            $cli = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()])
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',   array('neq' => $cid)); //exclude current user from results  //###### not working......
            if (count($cli)>0) {
                $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
                $errors = array_merge($errors, array(Mage::helper('customer')->__('"%s" already used!',$label)));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this solution for some time. But I noticed that the form.php file that you reference is the 1.5 version of magento. In version 1.6 the file is different ... Where to put this code in version 1.6? Thank you.

I found the file. It is in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/form.php.
But I put the code and did not work here ... I keep trying a solution.

Comment: added after:
    if ($result !== true) {
                $errors = array_merge($errors, $result);
            } ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event :

```
<customer_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <mymodule_customer_save_before>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>checkUniqueAttribute</method>
                    </mymodule_customer_save_before>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_before>
```

And in your observer :

```
/**
     * Check customer attribute which must be unique
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     * @@see customer_save_before
     */
    public function checkUniqueAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        foreach ($customer->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsUnique()) {
                $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $customer->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',   array('neq' => $customer->getId()));

                if ($collection->getSize()) {
                    Mage::throwException(sprintf(
                        'The value %s for %s is already used',
                        $customer->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()),
                        $attribute->getStoreLabel()
                    ));
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
```